# Single quotes as special characters in elisp regex

Tags: emacs, elisp

```
(defun string-is-capitalized (str)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (string-match-p "\\`[A-Z]*\\'" str)))
```

in the above regex, what does the single quotes backward & forward ` & ' do? i don't see it as a special code in gnu page, http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The backslash-backtick `` \` `` matches the empty string only at the front of the string or buffer being matched, while backslash-single-quote `\'` matches the empty string only at the end of the string or buffer being matched. You can find them documented in the [Regexp Backlash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html#Regexp-Backslash).